# Heart rate monitor only app for watchOS 2 records extra calories and shows exercise

Tags: swift2, watchos-2, healthkit

Basically I am working on a sleep monitoring application that monitors heart rate as well. So, I don't want to start any workout activity but I think that's the way apple works!

Here's the heart rate only code I am using:

```
@IBOutlet private weak var label: WKInterfaceLabel!
@IBOutlet private weak var deviceLabel : WKInterfaceLabel!
@IBOutlet private weak var heart: WKInterfaceImage!
@IBOutlet private weak var startStopButton : WKInterfaceButton!

let healthStore = HKHealthStore()

//State of the app - is the workout activated
var workoutActive = false

// define the activity type and location
var workoutSession : HKWorkoutSession?
let heartRateUnit = HKUnit(fromString: "count/min")
var anchor = HKQueryAnchor(fromValue: Int(HKAnchoredObjectQueryNoAnchor))


override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)
}

override func willActivate() {
    super.willActivate()

    guard HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() == true else {
        label.setText("not available")
        return
    }

    guard let quantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate) else {
        displayNotAllowed()
        return
    }

    let dataTypes = Set(arrayLiteral: quantityType)
    healthStore.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(nil, readTypes: dataTypes) { (success, error) -> Void in
        if success == false {
            self.displayNotAllowed()
        }
    }
}

func displayNotAllowed() {
    label.setText("not allowed")
}

func workoutSession(workoutSession: HKWorkoutSession, didChangeToState toState: HKWorkoutSessionState, fromState: HKWorkoutSessionState, date: NSDate) {
    switch toState {
    case .Running:
        workoutDidStart(date)
    case .Ended:
        workoutDidEnd(date)
    default:
        print("Unexpected state \(toState)")
    }
}

func workoutSession(workoutSession: HKWorkoutSession, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    // Do nothing for now
    NSLog("Workout error: \(error.userInfo)")
}

func workoutDidStart(date : NSDate) {
    if let query = createHeartRateStreamingQuery(date) {
        healthStore.executeQuery(query)
    } else {
        label.setText("cannot start")
    }
}

func workoutDidEnd(date : NSDate) {
    if let query = createHeartRateStreamingQuery(date) {
        healthStore.stopQuery(query)
        label.setText("---")
    } else {
        label.setText("cannot stop")
    }
}

// MARK: - Actions
@IBAction func startBtnTapped() {
    if (self.workoutActive) {
        //finish the current workout
        self.workoutActive = false
        self.startStopButton.setTitle("Start")
        if let workout = self.workoutSession {
            healthStore.endWorkoutSession(workout)
        }
    } else {
        //start a new workout
        self.workoutActive = true
        self.startStopButton.setTitle("Stop")
        startWorkout()
    }

}

func startWorkout() {
    self.workoutSession = HKWorkoutSession(activityType: HKWorkoutActivityType.CrossTraining, locationType: HKWorkoutSessionLocationType.Indoor)
    self.workoutSession?.delegate = self
    healthStore.startWorkoutSession(self.workoutSession!)
}

func createHeartRateStreamingQuery(workoutStartDate: NSDate) -> HKQuery? {
    // adding predicate will not work
     // let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(workoutStartDate, endDate: nil, options: HKQueryOptions.None)

    guard let quantityType = HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate) else { return nil }

    let heartRateQuery = HKAnchoredObjectQuery(type: quantityType, predicate: nil, anchor: anchor, limit: Int(HKObjectQueryNoLimit)) { (query, sampleObjects, deletedObjects, newAnchor, error) -> Void in
        guard let newAnchor = newAnchor else {return} 
        self.anchor = newAnchor
        self.updateHeartRate(sampleObjects)
    }

    heartRateQuery.updateHandler = {(query, samples, deleteObjects, newAnchor, error) -> Void in
        self.anchor = newAnchor!
        self.updateHeartRate(samples)
    }
    return heartRateQuery
}

func updateHeartRate(samples: [HKSample]?) {
    guard let heartRateSamples = samples as? [HKQuantitySample] else {return}

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        guard let sample = heartRateSamples.first else{return}
        let value = sample.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(self.heartRateUnit)
        self.label.setText(String(UInt16(value)))

        // retrieve source from sample
        let name = sample.sourceRevision.source.name
        self.updateDeviceName(name)
        self.animateHeart()
    }
}

func updateDeviceName(deviceName: String) {
    deviceLabel.setText(deviceName)
}

func animateHeart() {
    self.animateWithDuration(0.5) {
        self.heart.setWidth(60)
        self.heart.setHeight(90)
    }

    let when = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.5 * double_t(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
    dispatch_after(when, queue) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
                self.heart.setWidth(50)
                self.heart.setHeight(80)
            })
        })
    }
} }
```

To summarize, the unexpected observations are:
1. The time I monitor the heart rate contributes to the green ring in the activity app.
2. Unexpected high amount of calories are being recorded i.e. when the person is on bed or asleep!

Can you please help with the correct code that helps me to monitor and display a person's heart beat at regular interval during his sleep without contributing to the green ring or contributing extra cals. ?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting a workout and running the heart rate monitor will drain the apple watch's battery after about 6 hours (if it has a full charge), so having it run continuously while sleeping is probably not realistic at this time.

From what I can tell, starting a workout using workoutSession does 2 things for your app. It keeps your app in the foreground, and it starts taking heart rate sample every few seconds. Have you considered not starting it? Your health kit queries will still work as is and the heart rate monitor still records the users heart rate every 15 minutes or so. The main thing you loose is keeping your app in the foreground, and I am wondering if you need to do that (since the user will be asleep).

To retrieve the last heart rate sample from healthkit:

```
func getLatestHeartRate() {
    let quantityType = HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate)!
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key:HKSampleSortIdentifierStartDate, ascending: false)
    let sampleQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: quantityType, predicate: nil, limit: 1, sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor])
        { (sampleQuery, results, error ) -> Void in

    }
    self.healthStore.executeQuery(sampleQuery)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to retrieve the last recorded heart rate from the health app on the will activate function i.e when the user opens the app again? Also, if the app's not in foreground, would the global dispatch queue die? I am noting the time asleep as well, so need that data too!

Comment: To get the last recorded heart rate value from health kit, you can create your query where you sort the heart rates by create date descending, and then have it return just the first item. The global dispatch queue and sleep date should not die - the app is suspended in the background but not killed so memory is preserved when it is brought to the foreground again.